# How can I redirect a webpage in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a simple website in c#, I have a login system and I want to redirect a user to a new home page once they are logged in, how do I do this?

Also how do I redirect someone to a new page at the click of a button? e.g click btnMath redirects user to MathPage.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("url");
```

You can do the above

Comment: Thank you, I have tried Response.Redirect before and it wasn't working, turns out I just got the syntax wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

there are many method available to do so. One of those is response.redirect

```
Response.Redirect("MathPage.aspx")
```

Remember to mention path correctly inside response.redirect.

You can read this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/two-approaches-to-redirection-in-aspnet/) as well.